# Google Maps javascript API not loading after tab has been open for long time with 403 response

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps

So we have a page that uses angular and has a few tabs, and a few of the tabs have google maps on them, but they're loaded lazily and only when they're needed. When the page is opened, all the maps and tabs work fine but if the tab is opened for a while then a new tab with a map is clicked into, the map won't load as in it just shows grey space and in the console I see errors that look like

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (OK)
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/StaticMapService.GetMapImage?1m2&1i…070430&2e1&1u573&2u5355&&token=44361
```

I'm a little confused because 403 usually means forbidden but it says OK? I've checked my quotas and it's not even close to hitting any rate limits or quotas. Any help on why this is happening would be helpful or advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably some of google static(for example gstatic.google.com,googleapis.com) file centers have been blocked by your Internet service provider or even your country.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't the case because the maps work initially when the page is loaded, it's just dynamically loaded maps don't work after the tab has been open for a long period of time.

Comment: when I open the URL in browser I get this :
The Google Maps API server rejected your request. The Google Maps JavaScript API must be downloaded directly from Google's servers. Learn more: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API